# proving the product of two adjancent matrice

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-multiplication

Let A be an undirected graph G=(V,E) then the product AA represent gives the number of walks of length 2 from vertex i to vertex j. I found this on Wikipedia, but cannot find a proof for this. How can one prove this?

Comment: Do you want a formal proof, or are you just trying to convince yourself that it is so? Incidentally, this works for directed graphs as well.

Comment: @beaker an informal proof is alright.

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 1 here: https://people.math.osu.edu/husen.1/teaching/sp2003/571/graphs.pdf. This shows a proof for the general case of walks of length `k` for `A^k`.